# Controlling output voltage using Arduino

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, voltage, relay, step-up

I want to control the temperature of a heat pad, which heats up using a power and ground pin, and is controlled by a pressure sensor.
The micro controller I am using runs onl 3.3V but the desired amount of heat I would like to generate needs between 5-12V. 
I’ve done some research and I have come across a step up module or a relay, in order to increase the voltage. 
Would one those be sufficient? If not what would work best for this project? Would I need two different power supplies?

Comment: Start with  tolerance specs for ALL inputs and outputs that matter., V,I,P, BW setpoint  error etc

Answer (score 0):

You should first check the rating of heat pad , how much current is required or how much power is required

so you can calculate by P=V.I

that how much current is required now check that how much current micro controller can give

if its not sufficient than you have to connect second source for heat pad and use micro controller for switching

relays are good for high voltages like 220 or 240 but for 5 to 12 v relay is too much

you can use just transistor circuit for switching those 5 to 12v